# How to checkout a repository through SmartSVN / svn

Tags: ssh, svn

I am trying to checkout repository through SmartSVN but I keep getting this error message `Unable to coonect to a repository at URL svn+ssh://login@ip_address/path To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from ssh in the [tunnels] section of your Subveriso configuration file`. Okay so from this i tried to remove the -q option from ssh in [tunnels] section.

1. I went to .subversion/config file
2. In tunnel section everything was commented, but there was line

> #ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -q

I tried to remove the -q and uncomment the line but It is not working. Can I get some help to how to debug It or solve the problem that I cannot even checkout the repository ? thanks

Comment: What happens if you just run "ssh login@ip_address" on the command-line?

Comment: @jelmer so, I found out the problem was that since I was connecting through VPN, the hostname should have been localhost. And I am fairly certain that syntax of ssh in tunnel section was correct `ssh = ssh`, but where should I look for debugging info about ssh ?

Comment: @jelmer My bad, I came home from work tried It a it does nothing, just empty terminal row which timeouts after a while